# How to rotate a TextBox in Microsoft Report?

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting, reportviewer, microsoft-reporting

Hi
Is it possible to rotate objects (or just TextBoxes) in Microsoft report?
Like Vertical Text or rotating 45 degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample in my post will work for you, if you don't mind the fact that you will experience some degree of antialiasing when you rotate text [Invert or Flip Text in RDLC Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299969/invert-or-flip-text-in-rdlc-report)

Comment: Nice job, But its really painful to make a big report with this method... Also with your code, I can't design my report as well... I was looking for a built-in method to do this... Thanks for replay