# Invert or Flip Text in RDLC report

Tags: vba, fonts, rdlc

Okay, I've learned a bit more and have rephrased my question. I've got a need to flip or invert text 180 degrees (so it appears upside-down) on a RDLC report. I have some custom VB code that takes the text, converts it to a bitmap, then flips the rotates the canvas 180 degrees. The effect of this makes the text look a bit.. dithered... or fuzzy. It's not a sharp font anymore. The problem I'm experiencing is I'm using a special TTF Barcode font that creates something a scanner can read. When I flip the barcode font, the fuzziness isn't good since the barcode lines are so close together and the scanner cannot read it. Here's the code:

```
Function LoadImage(ByVal sImageText as String, iRotationAngle as Integer, ByVal sFontName as String, iFontSize as Integer)
Dim bmpImage As New Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1)
Dim iWidth As Integer = 0
Dim iHeight As Integer = 0

'// Create the Font object for the image text drawing.
Dim MyFont As New Drawing.Font(sFontName, iFontSize)  ', System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point)

'// Create a graphics object to measure the text's width and height.
Dim MyGraphics As Drawing.Graphics = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmpImage)

'// This is where the bitmap size is determined.
iWidth = MyGraphics.MeasureString(sImageText, MyFont).Width
iHeight = MyGraphics.MeasureString(sImageText, MyFont).Height

'// Create the bmpImage again with the correct size for the text and font.
bmpImage = New Drawing.Bitmap(bmpImage, New Drawing.Size(iWidth, iHeight))

'// Add the colors to the new bitmap.
MyGraphics = Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bmpImage)
MyGraphics.Clear(Drawing.Color.White)
MyGraphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
MyGraphics.TranslateTransform(iWidth,iHeight)
MyGraphics.RotateTransform(iRotationAngle)
MyGraphics.DrawString(sImageText, MyFont, New Drawing.SolidBrush(Drawing.Color.Black), 0, 0)
MyGraphics.Flush()

Dim stream As IO.MemoryStream = New IO.MemoryStream
Dim bitmapBytes As Byte()

'Create bitmap 
bmpImage.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
bitmapBytes = stream.ToArray
stream.Close()
bmpImage.Dispose()

Return bitmapBytes

End Function
```

I really don't know why there's not a built-in way to just flip text. It'll let me reverse it left-to-right. Ridiculous.

Thanks